# Easy sort list 2D by column

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I'm quiet new in Java data manipulation so I need some help if someone have a some good tips. Actually, I want just to find a easy way to sort a 2D list.

I create a list like this:

```
List<int[]> A = new ArrayList<int[]>();
A.add(new int[] {0,1});
A.add(new int[] {5,40});
A.add(new int[] {7,5});
```

And then I want to have a result sorted by the second element like:

```
0 -> 1
7 -> 5
5 -> 40.
```

I tried something like `Arrays.sort(A.toArray(), (int[]a, int[]b) -> a[0] - b[0]);` but it doesn't work.

Is there a simple solution to do that sort list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]));
```

or you can also do:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]));
```

If you want to sort into a new `List<int[]>` you can use `stream`:

```
List<int[]> listSorted = list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]))
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<Integer[]> A = new ArrayList<>();
A.add(new Integer[] {0,1});
A.add(new Integer[] {5,40});
A.add(new Integer[] {7,5});
    
A.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[1]));
    
for (Integer[] a : A) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        int[] temp = A.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < A.size(); j++) {
            int[] temp2 = A.get(j);
            if (temp[1] > temp2[1]) {
                A.set(i, temp2);
                A.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
```